# Addition of angular momenta in Landau's book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I am reading Landau & Lifshitz's [Quantum Mechancis](https://archive.org/details/landau-and-lifshitz-physics-textbooks-series/Vol%203%20-%20Landau%2C%20Lifshitz%20-%20Quantum%20mechanics%20-%20non-relativistic%20theory%20%283ed.%2C%201991%29/page/434/mode/2up). On page 434, section 106, the part about the addition of two angular momenta reads

> Let us begin with the simple case of the addition of two angular momenta to give a zero total angular momentum. Here we must evidently have $j_1=j_2$ and angular momentum components $m_1=-m_2$. Let $\psi_{jm}$ be the normalized wave functions of the states of one particle with angular momentum $j$ and component thereof $m$ (in the non-spinor representation). The required wave function $\psi_0$ of the system is the sum of the products of the wave functions of the two particles with opposite values of $m$:$$\psi_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2j+1}}\sum_{m=-j}^j(-1)^{j-m}\psi^{(1)}_{jm}\psi^{(2)}_{j,-m},\tag{106.2}$$where $j$ is the common value of $j_1$ and $j_2$. The factor preceding the sum is due to the normalization. The coefficients in the sum must all have the same absolute value, since all values of the components $m$ of the angular momenta of the particles are equally probable.

I don't understand the last sentence that all values of the components $m$ of the angular momenta of the particles are equally probable. Can someone explain it?

Comment: *m* for a particle, say (1), is the eigenvalue of $L_z$ on its *normalized* eigenvectors, so each has the same normalization as that for any other eigenvalue. Particle (2) has its *m* simply anticorreclatfd to that of (1). Can you explain your confusion better?